# How to use maxout in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, activation-function

guys! I have a question to ask.If I want to use maxout as activation function , how should I write the codes in Tensorflow? An input parameter is required in the slim.maxout() function, so it cannot be used for 
slim.arg_scope([slim.conv], activation_fn=slim.maxout)?What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to define `maxout` in a separate function. For example:

```
def maxout(inputs,num_inputs):
  return slim.maxout(inputs,num_inputs)

slim.arg_scope([slim.conv],activation_fn=maxout)
```

*(I may have the arguments defined incorrectly in the `maxout` function.)*

In any case, I recommend that you switch to `tf.layers` (tf core API) because `tf.slim` seems to be in the works of being phased out.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16182#issuecomment-372397483